# How can i insert changes from datagridview to database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

As you can read from header, i had a problem with insert from datagridview. Here code of my shiny probram:

```
namespace LibrarianApp
{
    public partial class Start : Form
    {
        public Start()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Start_Load();
        }
        private static DataTable GetData(string SQLiteCommand)
        {
            string conString = "Data Source=Books.db;Version=3;";
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(conString);
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQLiteCommand, cnn);
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }
        private void Start_Load()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData("select * from Books where BookName like '%" + NameTextBox.Text + "%' and AuthorName like '%" + AuthorTextBox.Text + "%' and Genre like '%" + GenreTextBox.Text + "%'");
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
            dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false; dataGridView1.Columns["BookName"].HeaderText = "Название"; dataGridView1.Columns["AuthorName"].HeaderText = "Автор";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Genre"].HeaderText = "Жанр"; dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].HeaderText = "Количество в наличии";
        }

        private void SearchButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Start_Load();
        }

        private void AddBookButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddBookForm AddDialog = new AddBookForm();
            AddDialog.Show();
        }

        private void RefreshButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData("select * from Books");
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
            dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false; dataGridView1.Columns["BookName"].HeaderText = "Название"; dataGridView1.Columns["AuthorName"].HeaderText = "Автор";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Genre"].HeaderText = "Жанр"; dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].HeaderText = "Количество в наличии";
        }

        private void InsertFromGridButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string StrQuery;
            try
            {
                string conString = "Data Source=Books.db;Version=3;";
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand())
                    {
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ("
                                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Text + ", "
                                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Text + ");";
                            comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see i use datagridview datasourse straight from the .db file. And i think, that why i got that error: "DataGridViewCell" does not contain definition for 'Text'"
https://ibb.co/1M4YkZX

How can i fix this?

Comment: Let's start looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell?view=netcore-3.1) (It should be your first move). As you can see there is no property Text in a DataGridViewCell, but look at that interesting property named Value.

Comment: If you hold onto the DataAdapter, you can insert very easily with just `myDBAdapter.Update();`  Documentation has these exciting details too